# PHP - Correct User-Generated Content On Submission

Tags: php, regex, text, grammar

Is there an existing function or tool that corrects common grammar and spelling mistakes (laziness?), e.g.

- " im " = " I'm "
- " i " = " I "
- " u " = " you "
- " theres " = " there's "
- Capitalize first letter of a sentence
- Add a period at the end of the string
- etc.

I've found a lot of tools that offer grammar suggestions to a user as he/she types, but in the end I still have to trust the user to make those changes.

I want is to take this string:

"im really bad at grammar and u kno i dont care"

And turn it into this string:

"I'm really bad at grammar and you know I don't care."

I'll end up writing it myself if I don't find anything, but I'm sure this has been done before and I'll miss something obvious as I reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Uhm, what if the user *wants* to write something that's not correct or in a standard dictionary?

Comment: @deceze ur just lzy dont promoat lazyness

Comment: My stats tell me that there's a 20% difference in the bounce rate between pages with easily corrected grammar and good grammar. So, I don't really care what the author wants, I care what the users want.

Comment: What's your audience? What do they typically talk about? Just take "iTunes U" as an example. Should that be corrected to "Itunes you"? No, it'll make text incomprehensible. Or simply the "U of A". If your audience uses a lot of "made up" words or abbreviations like that, you'll have a real problem. A completely automated system will always give you such problems. If you're lucky and your audience produces very unambiguous text, you'll have very few of these, but you'll still have them.

Comment: @deceze It's a matter of there being significantly more "u"s than "U of A"s by a large margin. I'm willing to manually edit the one occurrence of U of A over the hundred or so of u kno wat.

Answer (score -1):

This will help you with some of it but not all of it

```
function Grammar($text){
global $text;
$text =  ereg_replace(" im "," I\'m ", $text);
$text =  ereg_replace(" im."," I\'m.", $text); 
$text =  ereg_replace(" u "," you ", $text); 
$text =  ereg_replace(" u."," you", $text); 
// etc etc
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
$user_post = $_POST['textarea'];

Grammar($user_post);

echo "User posted this: $text";
```

I use a similar function to filter cuss words and turn text into smilies, takes no time at all to process.

Comment: Completely leaving aside the feasibility of maintaining such a list of words, I'm voting you down for terrible coding style. You have a bad use of `global`, deprecated `ereg` functions, backslashes where none are needed and generally WET code.

Comment: thanks for explanation, this was gather from posts I've found here on this website so I don't take it personally. I try to learn from other's experiences. Had those posts been voted down and EXPLAINED I wouldn't have used them.

Comment: @bowlerae Thanks for the effort, I'll end up writing something like that myself if nothing currently exists. The function you're looking for is str_replace.